# Can combat manuals be merged onto an unit?

Tags: fire-emblem-heroes

After the update that introduced combat manuals, I started turning lots of my heroes into Combat Manuals.

I did go to the merge screen and simulated merging a manual onto a hero, and it seemed that it would work.

Is it really that way? I was sure I read somewhere they would not be usable for merging purposes.

I'm afraid that that is a bug or some unexpected behavior, and if they remove that possibility... Well... just so many of my GHB units will be abandoned forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the in-game help on Combat Manuals (emphasis added):

"In places where you might use an ally, such as **Merge Allies** or Inherit Skill, you can use a combat manual instead."

So, I'm fairly certain that it is supposed to work that way, since if it did not, combat manuals would be less useful for cleaning up your barracks.

Comment: Oof that's a relief. I kept only one of each GHB hero.

Comment: @MMalke - that I can tell, the limits on combat manuals have to do with only ever being able to represent a level 1 basic version of the hero.  As a fer instance, if you built out a Cordelia with new skills from inheritance, a merge, and/or an element blessing, then got a new Cordelia with a boon/bane you liked better, you wouldn't want to turn your old Cordelia into a manual - that would destroy all the extra investment, but a regular old merge would keep it.  Probably not a worry with GHB heroes though.

Comment: Personally, I am only making combat manuals out of level 1 heroes.  Anyone I've even remotely spent time on is still in my barracks.